# Jump to second slide in ion slide box

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic to develop android app and I have a ion slide box:
This slide box is in html that is associated with state `Bill`

```
<ion-slide-box>
<ion-slide>
</ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

I want to show first slide if user is not coming from state `a` but show it otherwise.

I am using `$state.go('Bill')`. Is there a way to jump to second slide directly in case it is coming from state `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` service in your controller to handle slider from controller. In your case you can use `slide(to, [speed])` function like this:

```
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(2, [10])
```

Here is [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)

And Regarding state check. Whenever state is changed, event `$stateChangeSuccess` is fired. You can check from data associated to this event that from which state it came like this and use `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` to navigate to second slider.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    //use fromState variable to put your logic
 })
```